# How to manage and synchronize database calls with multiple application Instances?

Tags: c#, mysql

I Have One Database with around 4 millions records in my one server And I have One console application that is fetching from DB and process that data. Each time it fetches 1000 records for process. Now I have two servers and same instances are running in both server. How can synchronize Both calls with Database so it's not use unnecessary calls.

For Example:-

First take 0-1000 thn second will do the same 1000-2000 and so on. means instances will not same record and processed records again.

I am using mysql as database and C# as language.

Please guide me that How can I make this process faster reliable. Thanks

Comment: you should do two things imho, but since I'm a beginner in C# I'll not fill up an answer. You should first process your rows using transactions and you should keep track of the records you have already processed. You can do that adding a boolean field in your table.

Comment: But for this I have to do lot of update query. I want to minimize this process

Comment: If you're editing your data, you can't run way from setting up ACID properties via transactions. But maybe I didn't get the problem if you think it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You dont. Or - you put work items in a queue and have the agents pull orders from the queue then process.

That requires some queueing solution, either a proper one or something you hammer together in mysql.

Comment: Please give me some more details.